# Regular Expression to return false if anything in the string is other than exactly what the pattern checks for

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I'm trying to make a pattern that will return false if there's ANYTHING in the string other than exactly what the pattern checks for.

I believe that this is supposed to be achieved by putting the entire pattern between a "^" and a "$".

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim cellValue As String
    cellValue = "7:11 AM NBR Unavail"

    Dim callPattern As String
    callPattern = "^[1]{0,1}[1-9][:][0-9]{2}[ ]AM|PM$"

    Dim regEx As New RegExp

    With regEx
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = callPattern
    End With

    If regEx.Test(cellValue) Then
        MsgBox ("Got it!")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Don't got it...")
    End If
End Sub
```

The variable cellValue has text after the AM|PM that the pattern checks for, yet when I run it I still get the "Got it!" message.

I experimented with the following string and pattern earlier and the "$" at the end worked as intended. Why isn't it working with the above code?

```
cellValue = "7:11 PM (555) 444-3333"
callPattern = "^[1]{0,1}[1-9][:][0-9]{2}[ ]AM|PM[ ][(][0-9]{3}[)][ ][0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{4}$"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to enclose parenthesis between AM|PM as following.
`callPattern = "^[1]{0,1}[1-9][:][0-9]{2}[ ](AM|PM)$"`

Your pattern means
"`^[1]{0,1}[1-9][:][0-9]{2}[ ]AM`" or "`PM$`"

also second pattern means
"`^[1]{0,1}[1-9][:][0-9]{2}[ ]AM`" or "`PM[ ][(][0-9]{3}[)][ ][0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{4}$`"

Comment: You're correct, thank you. None of the documentation or examples I read showed how to include entire words in the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the pattern down to this:

```
^1?[1-9]:\d{2} (AM|PM) \(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}$
```

> [Test it here](https://regex101.com/r/Ce8Ccj/1/)